# SP_WhoIsActive - RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE_QUERY_COMPILE

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, performance, performance-tuning

Had an issue with one of our production servers earlier today. Many transactions were suspended with RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE_QUERY_COMPILE wait.
Have sp_whoisactive data logged to table every minute. Below is a snippet from it. It is ordered by USED_MEMORY.

[image]

Can someone help me understand the unit of measure for Used_Memory please or should i be looking at other measure to find the query that caused the memory pressure.

Updated Pic of the same session :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The [sp_WhoIsActive documentation](http://whoisactive.com/docs/07_default/) says:

> The [used_memory] column is also reported based on a number of 8 KB pages. The number a combination of both procedure cache memory and workspace memory grant.

However, I need to point out a few things in your question:

- Queries that are waiting on compilation memory aren't shown in your screenshot
- Those queries waiting for compilation memory are looking for [a different kind of memory (gateways)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/support_sql_france/2012/02/07/sql-server-compilation-gateways-and-resource_semaphore_query_compile/) - I'm not saying you don't have memory pressure, I'm just saying I probably wouldn't sort by memory_used to track the problem down
- Your screenshot shows a serious blocking issue - queries have been waiting minutes (not seconds) because they're blocked by others

In your case, I'd start by troubleshooting the lead blocker. Don't worry about the queries waiting to compile - they haven't even started yet. In your scenario, the last thing you should be doing is starting even more queries, which are likely to just get blocked anyway and consume more workspace memory while they wait. Get the lead blocker out of the way instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Brent. I have updated screenshot showing the compilation waits. This is ordered by blocked_session_count. There were a number of lead blockers waiting on resource_semaphore_query_compile.

Comment: @Halt_And_Catch_Fire OK, cool, but you're pretty far along the point of changing the question now. Your original question was, what's the unit of measure for sp_WhoIsActive's used_memory column? I answered that, and now you've switched it to ask something totally different. I'd love to keep helping, but I don't see a quick question-and-answer here that fits the Stack Overflow philosophy well - this is more like collaborative troubleshooting. Best of luck on the issue.

Comment: My bad.  Didn't mean to deviate completely from the original question. Thank you very much for the help :)